# Python Crawler is ignoring links on page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

So I wrote a crawler for my friend that will go through a large list of web pages that are search results, pull all the links off the page, check if they're in the output file and add if they're not there. It took a lot of debugging but it works great! Unfortunately, the little bugger is really picky about which anchored tags it deems important enough to add.

Here's the code:

```
#!C:\Python27\Python.exe
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urljoin #urljoin is a class that's included in urlparse
import urllib2
import requests #not necessary but keeping here in case additions to code in future

urls_filename = "myurls.txt" #this is the input text file,list of urls or objects to scan
output_filename = "output.txt" #this is the output file that you will export to Excel
keyword = "skin" #optional keyword, not used for this script. Ignore

with open(urls_filename, "r") as f:   
    url_list = f.read() #This command opens the input text file and reads the information inside it

with open(output_filename, "w") as f: 
    for url in url_list.split("\n"):  #This command splits the text file into separate      lines so it's easier to scan               
            hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} #This (attempts) to tell the webpage that the program is a Firefox browser
            try:
                    response = urllib2.urlopen(url) #tells program to open the url from the text file
            except:
                    print "Could not access", url
                    continue
            page = response.read() #this assigns a variable to the open page. like algebra, X=page opened
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page) #we are feeding the variable to BeautifulSoup so it can analyze it
            urls_all = soup('a') #beautiful soup is analyzing all the 'anchored' links in the page
            for link in urls_all:
                    if('href' in dict(link.attrs)):
                            url = urljoin(url, link['href']) #this combines the relative link e.g. "/support/contactus.html" and adds to domain 
                    if url.find("'")!=-1: continue #explicit statement that the value is not void. if it's NOT void, continue
                    url=url.split('#')[0]
                    if (url[0:4] == 'http' and url not in output_filename): #this checks if the item is a webpage and if it's already in the list
                            f.write(url + "\n") #if it's not in the list, it writes it to the output_filename
```

It works great except for the following link:
https://research.bidmc.harvard.edu/TVO/tvotech.asp

This link has a number of  like "tvotech.asp?Submit=List&ID=796" and it's straight up ignoring them. The only anchor that goes into my output file is the main page itself. It's bizarre because looking at the source code, their anchors are pretty standard, like-

They have 'a' and 'href', I see no reason bs4 would just pass it and only include the main link. Please help. I've tried removing http from line 30 or changing it to https and that just removes all the results, not even the main page comes into the output.

Answer (score 0):

that's cause one of the links there has a mailto in its href, it is then set to the `url` parameter and break the rest of the links as well cause the don't pass the `url[0:4] == 'http'` condition, it looks like this:

```
mailto:research@bidmc.harvard.edu?subject=Question about TVO Available Technology Abstracts
```

you should either filter it out or not use the same argument `url` in the loop, note the change to **url1**:

```
for link in urls_all:
    if('href' in dict(link.attrs)):
            url1 = urljoin(url, link['href']) #this combines the relative link e.g. "/support/contactus.html" and adds to domain 
    if url1.find("'")!=-1: continue #explicit statement that the value is not void. if it's NOT void, continue
    url1=url1.split('#')[0]
    if (url1[0:4] == 'http' and url1 not in output_filename): #this checks if the item is a webpage and if it's already in the list
            f.write(url1 + "\n") #if it's not in the list, it writes it to the output_filename
```